Xcode 16.2 and Xcode 16.2 beta "The tunnel connection failed"
I have installed iOS 18.3 on my iPhone SE (second generation)
after installing the beta version it stops running on my device.
I have already tried to install the Xcode 16.2 beta version and did the settings on Xcode (sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer).
but still got this error "Previous preparation error: The tunnel connection failed while the system tried to connect to the device.; The tunnel connection failed while the system tried to connect to the device."
also I tried to turn off the beta version on my iPhone but unfortunately, I still got the same issue now.
I tried every solution from cleaning the caches and everything to restarting my Mac and iPhone but nothing worked and I don't want to erase the iPhone and back to the older version.
Any suggestions?

